# max-width is being ignored when there are no spaces in between words

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

The max width is being ignored when are are no spaces in between words. Is there any way to override, or fix this?

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest
</div>
```

Comment: `word-wrap: break-word`, I'm sure this question has been asked before. [Browser support is good.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=word-break)

Comment: @misterManSam works. Post as answer if you want points.

Comment: @mistermansam No answers showned up because I didn't search it using the keyword 'wordwrap'. Didn't even know what it was.

Comment: No worries, it can be difficult if you don't have the right keyword. I did not downvote as the question is fine and will serve as another signpost to the answer.

Comment: I agree with @misterManSam ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the word-wrap css property.

```
word-wrap: break-word
```

Comment: Doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: sorry, I forgot hhh, I mean word-wrap: break-word...not white-space...Iwill edit